# ionic 2 error : trying to access a function of an external component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to inject an ionic buit-in component into my main component so i can call it from any function of my main component .

this is my main component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform , LoadingController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen,NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';



@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers:[NativeStorage]
})
export class MyApp {
  constructor(platform: Platform,private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,public settings: NativeStorage) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
      this.loadingCtrl.create({content:'loading..'}).present();
    });
    this.isSetup();
  }

  isSetup(){
    this.settings.getItem('ok').then(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.log(error)
    )
  }


}
```

PS 1 : i have installed the native-storage plugin ;

PS 2 : i got the error : Property 'getItem' does not exist on type 'NativeStorage' but when i call the component directly using NativeStorage.getItem.... it works so i think there is a problem in the syntax .

thanks .